# Joda DateTime vs Instant

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm using `Joda`, and I'm making a class to store the timestamp for a transaction and persist to a DB. Should I be using an `Instant` or a `DateTime`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use whichever one best fits your model. `Instant` is a representation of a millisecond timestamp value, `DateTime` is a calendar-based object. Each one can be easily converted into the other, so there's no need to restrict your model according what the database needs.

So you need to ask yourself - what data am I actually modelling?  Is it a year/month/day/hour/minute/second/etc value, or is it just an arbitrary moment in time with no particular meaning?

Comment: Also note that DateTime and Instant share the same base class (AbstractInstant)

Comment: I agree with this answer. I'll simply add that when in doubt, use `DateTime`. Focusing on milliseconds usually leads to frustration and errors as date-time is a tricky problem.

Comment: DateTime also has millisecond accuracy

Comment: @skaffman I don't understand your last sentence `Is it a year/month/day/hour/minute/second/etc value, or is it just an arbitrary moment in time with no particular meaning?`. Whatever I'm storing has a particular meaning, no? I'm still not sure which one to pick.

Comment: @krookedking I think he means are you storing something that only a machine needs to understand, or is this a year/month/day/etc that a human is looking at?

Comment: This is quite revealing http://blog.joda.org/2009/11/why-jsr-310-isn-joda-time_4941.html